# How to activate MySQL general log in version >= 5.6?

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble to activate general logs in `mysql` since version 5.6.

What is the proper way to do it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I managed to do it :

1. Edit your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`and add the following at the end of the file :

   ```
   [mysqld]
   general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
   general_log = 1
   ```
2. Connect through `mysql` (`mysql -u <username> -p`) and run :

   ```
   SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;
   ```
3. Restart `mysql` :

   ```
   sudo service mysql restart
   ```

---

*Note :*

If general log is still not working, try to manually create the log file :

```
touch /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

Comment: Should be `SET GLOBAL general_log = 1;` as mysq gives an error